# Do Roman numerals have on and kun readings?

Tags: readings, orthography, numbers

I know that kanji numbers can be read using on and kun readings. Does the same apply to Roman numerals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roman numerals (ローマ数字 *rōma sūji*) represent **numbers**. It's the numbers that have readings, no matter what numeral system you use to represent them. Roman numerals are thus read according to the number they represent:

> [I]{いち}, [II]{に}, [III]{さん}, [I​V]{し・よん}, [V]{ご}, [VI]{ろく}, [VII]{なな・しち}, [VIII]{はち}, [IX]{きゅう}, [X]{じゅう}, ..., [L]{ごじゅう}, ...

just like if you used 漢数字 *kansūji* (一、二、三、四、…) or アラビア数字 *arabia sūji* (1, 2, 3, 4, ...).

To refer to a Roman numeral, you could say ローマ数字の「じゅうろく」 for XVI.

Comment: So roman numbers only have an on reading.

Comment: The *kun* reading is usually used when a number appears together with a counter. But this combination would usually only appear with Arabic or Chinese numerals, as Roman numerals aren't part of standard orthography. I think you will have a hard time to find a Roman numeral which is supposed to be read with a *kun* reading (*hito*, *futa*, *mi*, etc.). This is more a question about orthography than about readings, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It represents numbers
0 零 zero/rei 1 一 itsu 2 二 ni 3 三 san 4 四 yon/shi/yo 5 五 go 6 六 roku 7 七 shitsu/nana 8 八 hatsu 9 九 ku/kyuu 10 十 jyuu
It represents others
a lot of... maybe 40+

Comment: Could you double check the spellings of itsu, shitsu, and hatsu?